# Best practices of wrapping an HTTP API for both Android and iOS

Tags: android, c++, ios, http, lib

I have some http REST APIs which are used for both android and iOS, however, this is not very easy to maintain once the API updated.

I prefer to wrap it in C/C++, so it could be used as JNI (dynamic library) or static linked with iOS.

But it seems Apple will force to use https, they do not support http anymore, I am not sure if there are similar libraries support this feature. Is there some best practices for doing this?